# problem for download counter when user uses download accelerators

Tags: laravel, download, counter, download-manager

I have implemented a route for users to download some files with laravel framework and I want to count the number of downloads for a file. So whenever the route is called I increment the counter for the file.

It's all ok until a user uses DOWNLOAD ACCELATORS (like IDM). It's because this software uses multiple connections to speed up downloading.

Is there a way to count actual downloads for a file (count download with IDM as one download)?